# Update last column header dynamically - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm hoping to update the last column in a pandas df using the first column header as a prefix. Using below as an example I want to update the col Z to include col X as X_Z.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'X' : [1,2,3],
        'Y' : [1,2,3],                  
        'Z' : [1,2,3],                 
    })

# Update all cols to include a consistent suffix
df.columns.values[-1:] = [str(col) + '_Col' for col in df.columns[-1:]]

# Update last col to include hard coded string
df.columns = [str(col) + '_Col' for col in df.columns]
```

Please note: I don't want to update this manually using the function below. The column headers will vary so I don't want to go back to check what the first column is and add it. I'm hoping to handle all cases.

```
 df.rename(columns={'Z': 'X_Z'}, inplace=True)
```

Intended Output:

```
   X  Y  X_Z
0  1  1    1
1  2  2    2
2  3  3    3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do this using list indexing and `f-strings`:

```
cols = df.columns
df = df.rename(columns={cols[-1]:f'{cols[0]}_{cols[-1]}'})

   X  Y  X_Z
0  1  1    1
1  2  2    2
2  3  3    3
```

---

Or we can adjust our columns list by index, then pass this adjusted list back:

```
cols = df.columns.tolist()
cols[-1] = f'{cols[0]}_{cols[-1]}'
df.columns = cols

   X  Y  X_Z
0  1  1    1
1  2  2    2
2  3  3    3
```

---

**Bonus**: weird out of the box list comprehension:

```
[df.columns[0] + '_' + col if idx+1 == df.shape[1] else col for idx, col in enumerate(df.columns)]

# Out
['X', 'Y', 'X_Z']
```

Comment: Great answer @Erfan